# Java program get no space left on device

Tags: java, unix, amazon-ec2, centos, filesystems

I'm running a java application on an AWS ec2, centos machine.
The application downloading lots of large zipped file , unzipped them, do some work on them and after the work has been finished it deletes the files.
In some point, on a specific zip file the java application exiting with an error of "not space left on device", while there is more than 700GB free.

I have run the df -H and df -i in order to make sure there is realy available disk space, which there was (I had more than 90% free in both inodes and space).

The FS type is ext4

do you have any idea what else could be the reason that could cause this error.

**Below the stack:**

```
Sep 10 00:53:21 Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/3a1dda94-1bcb-4027-9bd3-a88696a2addb/bal/GLLLL/Marketing/{889BDA00-D2FF-456D-A8E3-CEDF4E8B5FE8}/7751_2018-02-15T05-13-52Z.properties: No space left on device
Sep 10 00:53:21      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
Sep 10 00:53:21      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
Sep 10 00:53:21      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
Sep 10 00:53:21     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
Sep 10 00:53:21      at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
Sep 10 00:53:21     at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
```

Comment: edit your Q to show an `ls -l` listing of some of the files that were processed successfully (before your process deletes them). Also include the `ls -ld /path/to/tempfilesDir` for the directory (only) that contains those temp files. Without any real evidence, we can't help you. AND are you sure that the "specific zip file"  is not larger than 700GB when it is unziped? How long does the process take? If many minutes, then it could be possible. Maybe you should add logging to your process so you know exactly what file is failing, and then research it's size at the sending source. Good luck.

Comment: Did you verify that the free disk space is in fact on the partition that Java is complaining about? It doesn't help to have 700GB on `/` if you have 0GB on `/mnt/3a1d..`

Comment: yes i did :) after unzipping the file won't exceed 25GB and there is much space left on device.

Comment: @thatotherguy do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You have both space and inodes on this fs? What kind of fs is it?

Comment: it's ext4 on AWS instance i3xl

Comment: And yes i have more than 90% inodes and space